# How to store strings in the executable?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I can't use `Settings` because there's an external file. Is there any way to embed settings or otherwise embed data within the executable?

I need to be able to launch the application and have data saved from within and not loaded elsewhere.

Comment: Why not just regular embedded resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of data are you talking about? A file of strings? A single String of text? If it's a file, changing the "Build Action" property of the file to "Embedded Resource" will in fact embed the file.

If they are single strings, add a new file to your project, a Resources File (.resx), and mark that file as an "Embedded Resource".

Here's a similar question where there is code to show how to read a specific string: [read string from .resx file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508570/read-string-from-resx-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28VS.95%29.aspx) file for this.  It generates a nice static class to use and is easily localizable if you do multiple languages.