# How can I get a control's image property to string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Label` which loads an image from my project's resources. For example, as it looks in properties panel, image property contains something like this `AppName.My.Resources.Resources.x-image`. How can I get all this to a string? As it is!!! I tried this, `Label1.Image.ToString` but it returns this, `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and not `AppName.My.Resources.Resources.x-image`. Any idea?

Comment: Did I understand the question correctly? Are you looking for a way to get the string `"AppName.My.Resources.Resources.x-image"`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes my friend exactly!!!

Comment: [This post is for c# but I think it has what you want.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361685/how-to-get-name-by-string-value-from-a-net-resource-resx-file)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I converted it to vb.net but after some tries I can't understand how to use it, so I can't say if do the job!!! I am talking about the accepted answer from this question.

Comment: Even if you get it working it wont make the round trip - you will never get  anything like `My.Resources.Resources.FooImg` from a Control (as per title).  Especially if the image display changes (such as with a status) you would be better off loading the resource images to a `Dictionary(Of String, Image)`.  You can get them by key and your app wont leak