# get namespace of resx to access string

Tags: c#, resx

I am trying to access a resx in c# codebehind.

I've seen this answer:
[read string from .resx file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508570/read-string-from-resx-file-in-c-sharp)

, but have no idea what to put in place of "items" in this statement:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("items", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

where can i see the namespace of the resx?

Thanks

Comment: Is this resx file in your project? Do you know what resx file you're trying to read, or is it dynamic? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx

Comment: @TimS.Yes I have the resource in my project under a folder pages/app_localResources/MyPage.aspx.resx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
 string foo = GetLocalResourceObject("NameOfTheResource").ToString();
```

Comment: What is `GetLocalResourceObject`?