# C# put resource file call into a string

Tags: c#, string, namespaces, resources

How can I put a resource resx file call into a string?
@ResCont is my namespace and cnBulgaria is a string inside the resource file.

I try this:

```
string enresources = "@ResCont.Resources";

Text = enresources.cnBulgaria, Value = "3"
```

The expected result:
 **Text = @ResCont.Resources.cnBulgaria, Value = "3"**

Comment: Is that second line output or actual code? Either this isn't compilable to begin with, or you're leaving something out.

Comment: The bold text actually works. I just need to change @ResCont.Resources to a string since sometimes I use a different resource file.

Comment: You can do something like this with `Properties` class. If `resx` is another file (not class generated for you by properties editor), then you have to use `ResourceManager`, unless you make it properties too (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26184562/1997232)).