# How to open a file that is used in html5 game

Tags: html, asp.net, file, filesystems

How can I open an `.rsx` file? It is a file from the game in html5. The extension is rsx, but I think the other extension may be different in the RE$X format. This file is completely connected with a picture like png. I think that this picture is animated.  It doesn’t open with the program profile, which means that it does not have the rsx extension, but something else. I opened the notpad ++ program, but the code is not readable there.

The file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JSQ0ciup5iUza3XXZWvg-NVhTH9hTkHI
[image]

```
 [![RE$X         bundle_button_dynamic1.png   C’xЪн}    xTEУnuwBВѕИ
(ИbH ђ™њБ\]ЬPБ°%     BdQ"""в®(€2Јв€;о€*"nЁ€дVќ™фYиљМяЬ{џыЯ{їПЇы™јy{©Є®^NЏ РиwЂ„!pEеC•чЫяFYЖ>Ґ\в·БH«ьЫюt),Њ*mlњ\]*7TѕoЉrьSec7@7H©|»я‡яо)сOSмOoЃР±rnе'6eъ“Р Rнї|tВярфЛђ…IахFNИ›˜?Є4olюДъЁќµоБXUрЦ†Бй/‰ЯІ^къ\[VH0 хЉF\[r
ў
K­‰щ#иПµЛэш‘ЭШ&l™“m`¶\]wu
‹'•Ћ(•Я##Јэ©аеИњ
ъ$GЪдОЋC{ ,ХНкeХ-ё=4{Ыц8c
ю'=°>vсmиЕaШRяKRBЩM50"08ѓ ЧЃ~ј€‰dґ†™µяl‚^т3l©;‚”PЋAї-€CУЦ)6лџРяКЩ°Й>Цt3kN‚к\[jO† %”}Рљл$›хGиї16c"Щ­Е°^@РБ?Б–фн¤„ІЇ®µЦ›uфялъ9ХuЏџµГєЂ —ќ\[jјAJ(ы uЦ«lЦђУ°К1‘мѓЦcXЧфтС°%е#RBЩ­П°Ш¬ПBNП\(пI-ь¬ЪЂaЭIРЎ5`‹lAJ(ы 
Ц‘6kдZе˜HцA1¬:,¶@;RBЩ=†afіО‡њqШВгЁ…зыЎЌН¬Ѓ:Ѕr(„ч… &’}Р&лe6л(И™ЯК1‘мѓ6eX\[4п{ЬL$ыtёГz©НЪr–ЃrL$ыX›3¬\]  :"
Вї®Ѓ &’}Р«mtЧµЃњ5» Й>hK†5— #Ы@xя<`"ЩmЕ°$и¬џ!gc(ЗDІЪљaµ<к.пэ˜HцAЏeXПґY_ЂњWъ@9&’}РгЦбэ „ї~˜HцAЫ0¬lЦ9ђуБX(ЗDІЪ–a-%hюгЮЅ˜HцAЫ1¬A›u(дмЮе˜HцAЏgXЇ'hБУюґ˜HцAЫ3¬эlЦVђуk:”c"ЩнА°.$иШ:юаi`"ЩнИ°ц"иМ  –AЙ>и    л2‚¦BшќiАDІz"ГљiіЮЃZ Њ‰dґГєТfэВ;ъC Й>/С™aнnі…@эбЖDІЏх$†u-AЗх‡рkEАDІЪ…aнlіЦ†@іЅЖDІЪ•a}‚ EШD/џ L$ы ЭЦЋќсЪNЂ0&’}Рол&‚ЋGЏёеc`"ЩЧВ'3¬нlЦYиёВ˜Hц±f0¬a‚gCшщCАDІЏµГj3ЪB {'c"ЩЗљЙ°ѕFРґњgЦB ЙЎеYY.hГЪњ УГих„1‘мcнЙ°Ъ±DЙg~кL`"ЩНfXЫ¬C DµАDІЪ‹aЭEР  їCшQ„c"ЩЧВЅЦъ6k3њz„1‘мcнГ°о!иХ/@xЭA`"Щ=…a­MРiC`аkЖDІЪ—aэЃ g@xН"`"ЩнЗ°¦Щ¬Ѕ pic"ЩнП°юJРIУ ј\]&’}Р†UфЪ-†Ъ„‰d4А°&hiw/GАDІO‡ѓfЦфЪRЊЬ  aL$ыXsН¬±—~бЫџЂ &’}Ъd1¬v3MEu‡-Њ‰dk€aµ;зљW!|л*`"ЩА°Ъ*1u&­„0&’}РSV\['_б›:@ Й>иi«­юSЫA`кfc"Щ=ќaµЌnJMП}˜Hцµр«mкSо‚Ам\[ Њ‰dл™«н`¦м‚рМжАDІzГj»µ)йXШз°РПЙ>иЩ«нL§BёY1‘мУбsVЫ…OѕvCЙ>ЦЃ«=pLэ•Ќ‰dф\†Х®&·ЂАНEЖDІzГj’Ч^б‡!Ђ‰d_їћП°ЪCу58ѕ.^aL$ыX/`XнЂ`Zєґ‡РµЎѓAЩЅђaµГђТЭhжСЬ7Й>иE«ьL{ЭчtгX`”}uЅ˜aµC®Тёі/„1‘мcЅ„aµЅйн < Ј5L$ы —2¬vx9 гбІ!ЖDІ:€aµѓЪйПCё7юL$ы ѓV;”ћФ«J!Њ‰dtГjр3ЪCёv&’}–sГjO&ОДЅ&’}¬—3¬цdeЖ|wXL$ыъх
†Хћ"Ml Ѓ0мВDІЏu(ГjOМfbdЪј'0‘мѓcXнйаХ—Cаб¶ЖDІz%ГjOBg^‰Sь;˜HцAуV{к;a5П„0&’}Рб«=бћщ„SwB Й>и†Хћж—|‰Ўe.†˜№@І:’aЌ-.4З иlњ€О’}РQ«Ѕ¤Qr6 чЗDІ:љaµ<лJњl§г¤›¦ѕGµp>Гj/ЯcрюlВ˜HцAV{СhЦ=Pѕ}9д`"Щ§ГcV{аЏУЈ·BЙ>Ц±«Ѕ@6л'(Я8r0‘мc-dXнe№сГpрAЏ€‰dлUkl1°”Я·r0‘мугМ¬±%И"hЈИЉ‰dkГ\[ш<Кc\]1‘мcП°Ъ±ДёMШЪВ˜Hц±3¬±EЮ№P^”9EґИ;Ч-aXнҐе«>ѓАNc"ЩќА°Жґ„т32 Й>иХ«ЅЊ~Х l+ѓ0&’}Р‰klсю%(?яОсґ=т’:‰aµЌ®г¦ќ‹ Њ‰dґ”aЌmTм†Нџп†ю˜Hцхл5«Ѕ=2ѓЃчpr†‰dлd†5¶)s 6/›
э—СFЕїеL1іЖ¶‚Ж<€ЃсXc"ЩЗ:•aЌm@‚НЌ‘µ1±ті^kfЌm{ЌБQэњtc"ЩГЪ¦Xik/бF\[L·wиjЏ(.?ўґ°¤ёCF= u*ЉЮ1І(Ћ:f@
,WЌШN"эЁ­эA˜йяаЁїDя«8Ў  ˜•`ЕЉІ8аєд h†ЩI")с-Л.0'9@і¬¬8аъд вНЧnHРMWznrЂ\]‡“tЧ­4/9@WН0?9АIљaArЂОєТ7%и¤‹ґ09А‰єгnNРQй–${ZйЦд нu‘%h§‹ґ89Аqє–$h¬µх¶д,о#\]¤ҐЙVй"Эћ «.ТІ¤ \[ћЧEє#9§оL0HЧб®д “5`yrЂЩZ—V
ёоWи'ЋћwТИщ+    0IЧЎМ Ш 9Ќ@9&’ѓшЛџл"Эm Ь
9ѓ†Cщ Љ№о†аcЫ¶Gљл"­4 ®…њй
 ЙБmи©ч Ј!g~”П§Hg4wЈтќЄ«Ђђіh/”/ўаsDp¶®ГЅХ6kщ@,’гщVтрЇпFjЦ<ШІµ  Т@+Я}Х2дPҐm\]c`ёРюле6Г…Dг‰њ©ч oAОЛiЦ€rђкР_·ТЪдмa›fx 9елҐ\[i¤в5
KуЗw #H)н‚Y™ еЉэ–гЊ¤_ЏиSЫы\а PЋ¬Ю¶Э:gИЂ‡°@iP»кtRмLS
o№(bjЅm{(ўiFљф8MьIZ»`h‘@9"
BgД=A<‚ї. ц„ЕщEyҐ…гу'љП#axZЈЏ1=
µ<ЃYfпШ1¦А»УЋ†-У°З8Шюу|°e.Шг,˜r»Ц#eцkxДГ&t`Or°6cЅ°FШђl=лъ®жa{Љѓх
zaЗxљдivЖ#^XcO“lа`—6цБ<…ЬИБF^з…5с4Й3sЗа™}2ЊZbU ф

ЫddГРЅдG/\[SЏr=Л±щ”Лz    \[Тa{Ћc›9ИЗжйЂз6їNZ\[±%¶8¶‡Пц°5уфЫ‹›O•­7°¶НЫ-M|lћє•sl>°vxъ-М±-ЭжmЙж-ЩВ±щЗzЫУoЫЉ9^¶-‰pl>{іЮЗpШўЫк^Ю–lб©ЫK›ПL­\]-y™c\[·П\[·–-y…cуY·х©GK¶rlЏЇс±yґдUЋНз¬Э-yЌcЫ8ШЫ’­<-щ:Зжs
ЦW-yѓc{±ЋЏНгрЮдШ|NБъОЈ%Ы8¶HФЫ’­=-№ќcу9лOїнаШ^›кe;ЦЈ%oql>§`нчфЫNЋн­nЮ–<ЦУ’osl>§`эвй·w8¶ччxЩЋуФн\]ЋНз¬?<эцЗцйroK¶сш’ч96џS°ютXчЫWѕ(ЁЌЗ>дШ|NБ:мС’\]Ы)^¶¶ћє}Д±щќёґ$>6°й%Ж/ЈЮѕлвС”O8Fїc®ЦМ†OЖсэИ7фцШЭgЈЯ9(—nfГзгh‚ѕќл…рфбЈЯA¤єъ0v3ЊцЇѓ—с|ЏE|Й1ъќDљЛ"ІaГx!A+*јР+<љуЗиwйћ~ьљa<ѓ ПНтBЗxїбэОў–§їe\]рЦqўGWїгэЈЋ§ч2Њ=  ъаїЮВОт0~П1ъќF=O?юА0v!иЅе^иЌЭЊ?rЊ~ЗСАгц1ЊцбЊ»¦{лxіKWіб'Ј~iДп<Zyґg?ГjYЬП\[аЫ<¬?3¬FrўGѓ0¬х:пoЃпrйl6ьВ°ќH–G‹~eXSн eІ·АчxXcXЌЋ$иС¤ЯН¬Ѓѓц.жo^Ц5ЯёXя`XЌОдлA†хkыҐ‘‰^иC.‹Й†?VЈCмaэ‹aµчNПсХх‰
nmъ›a5:•QЛ9Д°Ъ'ўъщкєСГъГjt,ЕЛ9М°>BР“~цІѕаaэ—a5:—iЛ9В°.'hЛb/ґb¶\[‡+VЈѓ№a «®ш\[fЦ№­й›\[muі
Б°МMnm’a%Sьъ±єН/dЕ°Мв®)kb}{§—х—зП©«СБЬбЦaQѓaҐf
¬ЗЭеaM3іљLЩ·.Џ(ТН¬9»‰u±Ї®џ·(s±ЦdXЌfµ‡µГJ:¶ТэЪГZ›a5:˜uЬЪT‡aҐэя@«%^иnп/к2¬Fу˜‡µћ™Хr6tтBxXл3¬FуґЫK€Фи%ћ›нVД†Фhкaґ5ЪлЛs5ќ{­.\[4f FЛЩйЃ61CНкяЃЗ75e FюФmЖ@ЌЉёЗг%љ›ЎfmЪл^†-Є<РМ$vDK–pзAґb`‰wDk–pзAЛБо<€г8XВќС†ѓ%Ьym9XВќСЋѓ%ЬyЗs°„;ўЅэ>·Ц3‰ќСБИVЭОѓиИ±%Ьy'pl wД‰\[вќС‰cKёу :sl    wДI\[ВќС…cKёу єrl    wD7Ћ-бОѓиО±%Ьy'sl   wDЗ–pзAфаШо<€LЋ-бОѓИвШо<€ћ\[Вќ‘Н±%ЬyЅ8¶„;ў7З–pзAфбШо<€S8¶„;ў/З–pзAфгШо<€ю\[Вќ‘Г±%ЬyЋ-бОѓrl    wD.З–pзAX\[ВќвШо<€\[Вќq*З–pзAњЖ±%Ьy§sl    wД\[Вќq¦Ѓ-№ќqЗ˜pзAњН0Vїу Обо<€Ѓcх;в\Ћ1бОѓ8Џa¬~зAњП1&Ьy0ЊХп<€9Ж„;в"†±ъќq1З˜pзA\В0Vїу .ео<€Acх;b0З˜pзAa«Яy—qЊ  wДеcх;в
cr;b(ГZэОѓЖ°Vїу ®dX«Яyykх;b8ГZэОѓБ°Vїу FљY“ШyЈЦкwДh†µъќ‘П°Vїу 
ЦкwД†µъќ1–a­~зA2¬Хп<€«ЦкwД8†µъќQД°Vїу Ж3¬Iм<3¬Iм<”0¬Iм<L`X“ШyёљaMbзa"ГљДОГ$†5‰ќ‡R†5‰ќ‡kМ¬Йм<L6і&іу0…aMbзa*ГљДОГµk;УЦ$v¦3¬Iм<М0і&іу0“aMbзaMbзб:љДОГlљДОГљДОГх4‰ќ‡МРdvж2Р$vnd Iм<М3C«Яyh*жCMђPSїJsЩШ{ћНЕЁCoQЌ“7iВДВТ|з-Рq“сSth®©Ч¬Э¬іm{NХ;)b!ѓљqўХИ.i к­Ёq3ѓљЮГAНј‚«Uхi†ё…AMыВ…БuХSЬЉ(йAХУ—Т&Bf€EЯњe®X\[N((Иo‘ћb±‘/gxuИ±„б›»ЭИжь;»5(мрЭfж«Ё™!–2|у\[9ЁRмчеВЫ4ЯнFѕ@µИ±Њб\[0Уi•о›MoПm©єЗё§ёГМЧ :d†ё“гыЭ…ъ*nZQ¶Ґкежћв.3_укђb9Зч†µ*жnЫоЄЯ
3_лкђўЊг;ЯA\]ї{vЕЊmЫ\]эw·™ЇCuИ±’У—лФњЗЎў {ЭСП{М|=«Cf€UЯјС®—Л*Ў"ЅЄГwЇ™o`uИ±jг ог“GЅef!*ґ Ю\]Е}ц%ЗiҐц‹i`z?„ќЪQuёXх к!bRaс˜ўьјўВвьШлy~`'пWЕЃЅЕэфъ4Љїmз§¶іR/Н­з¶©¬°·
—ДБЅДZЁiРРЛљЧЈзС/мqgњ­Ћc;‹YRJу§Т{‡йGЯ4ЂcREХЇwлЋ~QqШFыEWТ^’­™+К"ЌЄ^T OAаИBc"ЩBUЊфХЂ‡’«z—X<њ`†®Г#Йк"=љ`™fx,9@YХыџвсд чVЅK,ћH®Vk†'“` €¬ТЂхIt+=•аЭqO'X©‹ґ!IЂ.ТЖд wл"=“$@чГ¦д eєHП&Рl€з’и"=џњj8/$Зp—fx19АR\]йНЙj*O0C«F89@ћ®Г–д э4 "9Хo\‹HrЂSt?D“њ®›хҐд зiАЛЙ©ЖEрJr­д0lMаФбХд N+Ѕ–Ай‡ЧЏ\…`Љ‚-˜H¶pj9SЮ80ш3¦П‚-˜H¶PS#ъксжСЂKя„`нsa&’­\[±YoХєґнhА%л X·'lБDІµДг5¶
ёшWЦЛ„-˜H¶nC†ы4Га%Цп\[0‘lРЂ·Н:›µ%6kK ЩnЦХєH;Џ4ѓАзы!Њ‰dkpV–ЛНјН04G†жГ*Эпк0+}+}H¶–"`­vп
2‚iwАL$\[

"k4аЅ$Ѕ·.ТыЙnЧНъArЂ›t+}˜`љо‡\]Й†к:|” ЏnҐЏ“s3ъj!сIхn† №єHџ&W$‡б3 Ј№±k&и­ љн‚ГNЬ:р%хБP7CЧбудnдxWwЬЙЭИб8ІЭЙ–иJ™а9
Ш“а\]‡Ї’ь­•плдо"ЄҐ+эMrЂ&љбЫд mtѕK o0{“њ¬ѕOтЄ-­K?$иў~Lтж,Н°/9АсєТ?nЁ9эЦП†ЧП¶їZ)РbE™s“Шo ь эqЅy4ШЯЉШ¶m{…3мюl мѓю›VГfL$‘ЎbЃЦЦА'РяP.l>DW7~b_љS±^~1 Ю†њ ј\]Џфvмz¤чt+эj ј9иК;РеE/Cp^AAЕпр›° rzн†т^tсП&ўзЋ¤kАпАrИ№|  ”c"9ёN?ьa Ь9г0Ћ 7A°ВЈK
Ђ©ђѓЮ®|хГФШЌMъвс§0rnьК1‘l_^”Ј;о/ rжaіОЈfНЏЭШТ3wB­†тщ«ќ;ЎПwИ 9ТЎЙ6А  °юINЅлi†ГЙ9ІљбЯд Ћ=I0A3T&7 <Vu
Ґ¤{Эo°ф<Ґ‡ЅЛ‘B›6k(Й!фСі5T Tz ц—Зkф¶з(К‘ќЫ¶GЏ«ЪoђЎКН¶ї*®˜ g«‚дhm4ЇбЄм/ rC{#Ti91°оxЉrЕ›hЖ^¶LAhЄz
BSC:еLЉІ5Ё А®лљЉР.h¶эЭv©ц"_авЗ(КСБ Цс>М–5љжЃR3Х¶$иЉхеиЙh$K«NьИ4„¦{ ЩцеUЃЧ:0”#geYUwYfЛt„ХфАЁ‰ТѓЌ€сЮ:ek-ШqZи\]7”љЁ¦Ѕш(lл@QОэ{ЅnўZ­н†ц &ЄeЯъµЪЃў:ЎNЗФFh”љЁvђ.\[ЬзњМ&9tш

­ѓРє(iRќ˜&Eќ­q’йNGл3Э1uZПҐfЄґЯQёл/Љr$Іў,ч9­„хZЯ­IЩДZ/g  A/wЦмIЋМ*(NТ®ЏРnЦLj¦ъЃmќуІE9І Тn`¶ХъF‚@?зШЙЎгСVПУ*Сђ±UAР\[_p (GЮ_Qm§ыµc«щ-_к@QЋЦЗ±і@іГШj7‚>мкW”+vўoэT·pcЖVйzЬА¬!ekШЉ2k¬†6alµAПqКС+P›–л7elµ!AпxЪЃўн‰vМј™БV¤ЩgеЇёмеИ“Ё€џл7gмµAЧ8;x$\[aЃ‡кОiБШ+mv&d8P”sAЈ›Ї±%cЇzЕZЉrи"н?СumЕШk{‚Югт†(‡є»iЩЪ`Ї uЋviЭ°OїХs,c«5‰сng€#9Іµ  wіnўг\[Ґп, ЊtЋN’™$гР6Њ­n&иф\[(Кґ
=\]і¶el•оЮd№МеPG4у‹tЗґ3ЫЄэ56Ѓ›\C2К‘Џ
ўu3ПШ*\]ЗxЮҐI(Gc:AЧµ=c«ф}ЃЗ{:P”)ЪЌ|©ЬЃ±UЫ^їЙЃўlao•hhGЖVУнрcЈ+ьШС<ґљ»5фЖVm•ёНE9Ъ‡Ц|4фDЖVKмрc‘+ьX‘gђх­ъќ\[Ќ…®e-БЎЎќ\[Ќ…§єВЏS!gї‘›5ф$ЖV/°ГЏ‡\бЗC„ќу…†valХv.+ћp…O@(sЫvЛqЯ\]™±uЄнТ\fЋr$›iї†vcм5‚Фr… µ т&Ћ­\]аоf{Ќ‡ Н\]!Hs€,А±Х±Ч“{Ґ“MЃI®°eZo‹ћЈЎЊЅЪБ@зХ’C8’D/Х¦Юѓ±WыґПЌ®aeк˜hg­€™ЊЅ^BРgњЈл$G›гШ:Y·pcЇ№цс$+КґшщVЧµ'cЇф
8Ѓy!ЉІ5ыХaН6Ы«эх    Ѓ~.Я„rtzюUЪ‹±W»…ouMPЋцGх_©\[ё7cЇ†$ткрOє…ы0цЪЭ‚XXc4фЖ^gЫ!ИPW2,@Ј\[ўлЪ—±Ч®†„ЮЦ€|­;§cЇЌ!HЁ7vN‘†цgм5жЦvєЬЪN{лВ:ЁЎ9ЊЅЖBђ;\]!Иќ8—Гсх5

0цj
AhіЃV?вР cЇeзR”#лРиОЧќ“k¶ЧШЖнЯs (‡NBSїL;‹±W\[‡зD\]x;ЗЧ®ZCЊЅЪУА§К(КСcq|ќЎЎ{=‹ Пv (УeЫ‘u\]Oeмu“ё|КЦХШЇ3u\]OcмХ†DЗ ф>НzєЩ^lVЧ”еh.ЄяjЭЇg0цzҐ!‰T Ѕю®Ўg2цЪЫ†X8И»Фя,Ж^—Ъa€ЛБ lҐРЙЭ9g3цZЗC\P”CyhЇ{5л9ЊЅЦ2„!Ў~ШВWлОИШлЫ­№f‘(G‚hкG4л№ЊЅv4„!‘чіІrЯФэzcЇC
a­EoСНt>cЇ¶6ЌZйљвЇґЧ$ўл~ЅАht±ЈОG…ТЯ#4C7У…FЈ‹}OVасU.•XСг*nРuЅИht2xAџuy   ”+ѕВAтЂnб‹ЌF§мЇяЬ:И5\
k*крхє®—Ќ.%v·Лk®Xв5€ЋГAr­fЅФht©ЃПнX"мЉ%В=
м@Ќ®†эµSюX"ІьЏnбБFЈK‹З.V”-ґ—1\]є9–HGЈsўрЛЊFWУK„Fa\]чйѕЬhtµвЛЮX"”‹–3U7УFЈ«М#и®реИ©Ы¶‡¤VяЎFЈ«cЊ%hb–»Sі3\]Эx,б\]О€Ь№m»Ли®4\]Ѕ@‘aћyGєБєsтЈ{Мcрн©\[x8ctэмє®qХu
DOXQVбЊк#Ј»‚ /^й@Q®@GщC«ДHЖи>&и’Эe‹NFОУ-<КltЖЂ Z‚~xќnбСЊСн0Сіph~P·p>ctзЪЃЛ#ўЩ†Ъ$4kct¦ЂАBkpEбcЈ3uРиоСЛќq\]byD\]аBіСЕпєDиTOrctѓ є©їE9B/ЦР¬гЈ3‘/p¤sЦБ‹Ј\[jX— ГsБЫµ"ЋgЊОґЮБx>z…®k1ct+MAнo8ТхС:\В\]Ap™:КС.8ТЭ¬<Ѓ1:ы™р^ЉrЕ>T‰CљхjЖицtY‘EЩВ±ХєIЧuўСrRвd\Јъ€ћ‹¬ЏкO2ZNjрTГЁy-'Uі–-§†qT§3ЙЦ\]ЧkЊ–“Х\]~e«!NBЧhиdЈе¤GхЋк‘ЯµO1ZNНш
ЃwTЎэ\[st\]§-§Vр<‚>=ЬЃў№pEЅR‡^kґњЪЖ‚ИW+Кr?ТРiFЛ©cХ)о®РРйFЛ©kњъF6 ъзйfљБXЋi)т\]?
ќЙXОIц’kЃeЪd«X¤ЅД,Жrb;HҐ®¤RЁ %фJ­ГЧ1–sДЮA:иЪA:€C†\·jиlЖrLCs;т„®лЖrъ†жЭcTSЧхzЖrLCі…ѓЃ5\[Co`,'64пq
Н{АjЊ¦оЊЇsН–cћ«— еь­›йFЖrLCsи\ҐзкПc,зt‚>1ПЃўTPЄ§ux>c9¦Ў™&+№џкє.`,З44УБаjн`nb,'Э0    ЌlВ@oґ†.d,Зґ—9ЊР ®лНЊеoпеё‚Z”Ј=іІ*њAтЖrb\[^G\лГG в †—RшVіечsиX«µD·р"ЖrL‹FСAБ<­Ub1c9¦с5т9ZN\]\]Ч%ЊедЖWЛ™„ЮЖXО~УшЪЬ3H.5Єz|Цм_Cўѓq¶чn7ЄMыЮѓА#.Џ€rd(Цµ‘V‰eFхЇe_#X‹ЬЇ4лFхЇmњ5G^QжRя;Ќк_З8ЊјЂЮ¬fЅ‹QяL§3рѓи 
\]ОЁГцHґП¶нwЖµ©‡\aPz}Лї•YсЋr)єuЛХ7mЌРmk™ЦЯ»Х7­їD/GMЪ¤\[w%Јъ\]dдkT‡єАч0Є 'єИ‰`Ў‡іnФРUfХЏ±р
ђ­±АOjиЅЊк›Иљ№µPЧu5ЈъцVж:—F92=SЭВч1Єo )xПu¶ЁЧ0Єя©aоAЕўwгРыХ7MК"еЁMEє–Q}SёUиѓПРНф ЈъЖГ9Nђ·.Ўзчv+Кў5µБ=ИЁїi§ЃјѕлtЖCЊъ›F№(­Т>Їь0ЈюЗN,DиVїЖъЈю¦QОBgE‡щгРGх7ЋrmQэ7кОyЊQУ(єЅ„Z>ОЁї}кfНЇ®ю"cСФ\[к?БЁїi”Ј<ЧЩ¤x’QУ(yзвzFэБ0іўн‚иЭ9O1кoZёЏ¦"фl
}љQяtУщ=їі№ЃQгщЃhtхtїndФЯx~ =їµRCџaФ б нЅ’§€C71кЯТ0КE ъ7ЧЈЬіх§xэЈњ…qЃµP7СsЊкП v@ХN+буЊк/4Њrґc-СMфЈъц¶ИЅM\]¬M!RЊх<N7С‹Њк›¦ЃBУiЄ8tіYхЌЈ\дYzХ/7«ѕqjБЃ ZЄЎaік›·вУ=§·0ЄoЬЉ?=я}є®Њк·вkЎк;ae„Q}Уi@=њuЇ†FХ7ЋrcpЋ^Ў›й%FхMЈ\')ЎЦZ%^NищЅЈњх ъаЕєАЇ0кoе:Ўъ;¶є•Qг№<:b±TЧхUFэЏµЗ›ѕ®с¦/DPҐйђhъЈю¦QЋBи\guлuFэЌgуP/\]кяЈГЖнйZиѕќSroљu86ЮшVЈйњOЕZНєЌСaгцt}ґњfљu;ЈГЖнй»1*Ѕ_Cw0:lљЮGqјЊј¬нх-F‡cGЭ\Щ(Gи¶Щ¶Ъ#оdtШ4TY8ЏsН6ЮftШ8TuCЈ‹jЦw6ћWѓAћsЋц\]F‡›ШОФЃЈLп†N€·pщћA‡j5TQњы·f|џС_гY5t,A'¬ьЂС_гNo\]Ф$зФШ‡Њю~jЪй=EYЕCєuw1ъkЬй=Y\[iЦЏэ5оф®ВЋqVс>6лЇyј™ђ•qЋ}ВиЇqјYYЎцZ  ?eфЧ4ЮРuЬ–3IщЊС_гСЇфБ\[uЃ?gфЧx~'c®IКЊюЪйнОх3$Gив““4ло„>Ш;ЮDСmXBЧхKF‡MGИ#Ї`вирі›7Nлг\О9IхЈГЫL§—deU8ћяkF‡Ќ§Н1рi«YїatШёqє›йЭ9Я2:loJСҐЅ©Yї3лp|јс‡JA>QіоetШ4ЮX8?sљьћСaгxУuш

эЃСaУxљЂ¦о­ю‘СaыҐ°Ел(КфPЁ»Цб}Њ›Ж›hЊ™њmЅџ6Ќ7TOzg1ЭoTDј`Ъ‡‚ОtЅ†юlTDaЮ‡lЌЉШQ7УЈ"љOY`\]џР¬їQ™Ћ©ШЇ;ґеьjTДу!єDј‹.рoFEL5ЦЯћиеwЈ"Ц0}°АoiиFEL3џу№Yх?hTДфА_ЅЩ№«ЊдИ<t¦=t3эiTДљЖЃ#Ъ\]x-Нъ—Qk™Пщ`З·jиЯЊ"љN G‡ЎGЬ ›йЈ€ЖmЅ¶;З?Њ"·хи\]Б§ґС6+ўЩыПДQэЭВя2ЉhфюµPOЦ>В(ўЙы‡ ;З  ~*E4zяюЁ€пVХUЈ€Жі/ЧєГ*Б(в^‚ОЯп@QЋ,@Џ˜\]ХLJ2ЉhтюС&и‡«^0ОVЉQDгЩ¬§Ј€*…QДе¦\]ІЫ¶лІU*Ј€Ж\]ІЁ€Э5k
FM§P¬З°_7кfJ3j“2%©ѓ-њ©Ўжч\]SЊ.<„bЋCНп»¦љ\]8rЮҐ›©–Q›j˜ПѓМpNyЄЪFmJ|@Р№Ќ(КфPи­ГuЊЪ”ntбС–ШВЗh®kФ¦љFЩ…гл6ЭВхm2n<TјЁYл3ЪdЬxкЊбe–†6`ґЙґ$gї»ЎЧUCF›Њ~˜ѕ/Ў—nбFЊ6™ьp€ўpнLХ1Њ6эр©ЁMџк76k“щЊДtбzb¦љ0Ъґ• і{9P”#‹Сзи7eґЙд‡ЈmђUЇ„ЁfЊ6ПH|–•|WC›3ЪdЬЗ№
}“фTF›Њы8ЭP›zлfjЙh“q‡e:s‡¶bґЙxдаФ¦ѕє_\[3Ъdr¦ЎЪhЇ›tЃЏeґЙxдаLФ¦ЭzњQ%jДNЎLuнm №
ЊҐUўЌQ%ТЊО4ЪЙЦє™ЪU"Э|nаK®фЃ3ХЋQ гЮF :˜—ґ6ПЁ„qo#і  ЪїjoCµ7Ё„iџ:Еr”°ЈFoHЯ‰РРЋЊ:˜јaЁ>ЄГ‹є‰N`ФБи
ў:и—VХ‰Њ:¬і_С:мzEл0D–„NУъЫ‰Q“7ЊvВлҐGХ™Qг^ъ·8Ю8кpЈЖх~¬z…шtaФБёЮЯХБТољРCшЦыЛСClХЧЌQ   ЈKЈ/@ґ4ґ;Ј&—FЯUjUиєћМЁ„СҐ\]ёў,тѓ®kЈЛм·l\]wЎ №=ДYљµЈЖSК\]±Аt\]3•0о/я€ѓЖn\]а,F%ЊЛзSqЉЇЯxR=•0.џчЛКЉћ¦њНЁ„qщь%ф†ЫµчbTВиТиѕжУ4ґ7Ј&—F_ѓjЅRµ®ъT‚оj>КҐ\]‚BїЇ­NaФЃѕќ!0В/ЎL@†ОХ­Ы—Q“K‹цАВvТ­ЫЏQгћлЂ >mЈъ›ХБјЌуЦЉљГЁѓi5љ^»‹ћ­ЎFЊ«Сo`lшћ†u0є4ъZCЗаru0№4ъRK±ѓІzџK
9Ё;'ДЁДX‚^жНQ¦LBj•АЁ„ЙҐE{aЃќд©ЊJ˜\Zдw4•8ЌQ  гвоl+ЯЦwєY%Њ‹»‘SйEdЭВg0*a\ЬЭ‰д'є™ОdTВиТ°н\FwЈ&—:ЋѕX7УЩЊJ\]NЬќуокF%О$иE®Z”йµЂРҐ:ђQ    “K‹цЕAЈGјszЁs
*AwВueМЯ8`мУъ{ЈЖ%ЦZ”Uи‡ФщЊ:˜–Xй№иЕљхFЊK¬`=їФJxЎYМ.
ЗФРљх"FL.-ФYЯУъ{1ЈF—6ЅЎТ¬—0к`/Шџн|55Й‘ыqвy™fЅ”QгЩГ ZM/Э9ѓ»•Дuєе(а,г7­„ѓН*a^мјgND:„Q УbgЈпи\]аЛ•0MІ-њ)\[{u_ОЁ„СҐќ€*q‰.рf•0єґPGlб\]љu(ЈF—v5NІУuїcTВЮ9
№F9”#лРCУР+•0№ґи Фag’ќЗЁ„}Уб;GФ:‰Ф›яjё±_Бём№ MЭ)рcїљwЋи\[°­џµ"Ћ4ц«Њы&пm3С“°_meмWeфMЎОопФhcї¦˜}У4њХСО7цkjмк№ѕ®»тP¦7яCъкDU`мWжЮ—3±™‚љuЊ±_У‚vѕИ5\]ёўйЫ¶з*
Лф«с* KQ‡х=MЄђйWУ”ЧВ•uPwОUж~5;˜nШЇCuЃЗ1эjr0!љUнС¬ELї>С:ћйЧ˜ѓЙu9˜\€`а­ыµШЬЇж
qЊ\,эТ…*aъuёэѕЛБ ­ђ\[CxУЇЖ+c.Г~ХЧY©«™~5Н\[­илєN4vЋ4z‰Pкрwє®“ЊќЈМ^b.ќ>y®JЌќ“?нbE™®ЌХРkЊќГЬ#Ѓ†dќ©ЭЪdcзФЪЧ”mЪеzW{DqјО­©Y§0ќcјдJ¬л8Н:•йУ,Т:и~‘^\]ЛtЋЙФC=QчiЦiLзMkm®л:ЭЬ9ж“»Р„Љ4tУ9ЖЌSє‡v .рL¦sмѓuZ:P”ЈMІІrлиfљЕtЋсБ‘Ш9%єАЧ1ќcљПYяў"¦кПf:ЗшCTД_ґеМa:ЗhЇ·`зґЦuЅЮШВМ{йW J8Ўф
ЖN
Ъsњ'\]«–(G\[`7РuќЛґ°iЕ'2CйR\]Ч™6®ш к‡ТuзМcZШdtцDhи|¦…ЌF·˜n…Хu\]Аґ°qѓ-Y/С-|УВц>дЈ®ЧјQ¦KґrхлYj!УВЖ—ЛiІr­nб›™6.ў ю†jлЯВґ°сD6MViи­L-зv,°>\]¤1-lЬtЌ:¬Пе©ЕLч!иѓ_;P”Јн°…\[hи¦…Ќ/!cDх%к6¦…Ќkйи%кл~\]Кґ°ЙrBGX•љхv¦…M–cЭ…-ЬYі.cZШёЏ3C®aљх¦…3єцЉrґгЉІ\З7Эinaу{®ҐШВsZT±ЮЕґ°qљ_gWъеµњiaг‰ЦУйЪ#­€+˜6YЋU†бe7НZЖґ°q\[d<ZО(Нz7УВц-О«Їr (G;cмпl<­dZШш:еT,р
Z%о1·°yЦ\oEYЁ©f\]Еґ°сјеЩХЇ«{™6YќЋ‹кcnj5УВЖ\]†‰8ѕ:ср}L·%иJ—oB™&+№нuз¬aZШ4ҐЇC‹ЮЁ|?УВЖщkCTДљu­№…Н    ПC“¦Ў0-lІk
¶p/ЭЇл˜6.ЬOЖ‘nњf}ђiaы+¤—p (Sџжћ ;з!s›ГKљУ-Р^вa¦…Ќ3Й&фeЎєsaZШxB§
!'ц7їлЄЊ–cС\]ћ}u3=Жґ°q|:z}ґzњia\[пИtщ¦L >НХwyЄ'ЊНd^щ  5GmrМ“ЖfFх\]Љ¦^GCЧ›IХЯzC®ЂV‰§ЊНД¬_‡ГU©f}ЪШL)сw\]\]Я’Ђrґ/6S††n`љЙ8»j…cN{­ННd>УtЭАўлъУL&¶ЗQ\]K‚ЪД4“qНфzчЭЂкY¦™ЊKUЊэќіjП1Нdњз‡*q‚VДзЌuFEґЦЈ©л\[жХЖє2л€sgЫ_p‡ѕh¬«ЉЯжж:‚r4„uuVа73u5О8ЪЎ?I7S9SW“6СбPз†n6ЧХј¶F—-й»‹Ф¦®цэ\[у®л¬=лкњ·¬`кjЊэ;ўGм¦Y#L\]M*AGќЫЌUФX`»ўшzЧKD(Уцtn®n¦—˜CйNиЦzhиЛLЃMэjmЖлл\]Х+LЃ+:УҐГ(GПГxШYЬКШ™vA/СSC_e
lкk:УБєАЇ1^OРЙ
(КС‹°А§kилLЃЌЃ^w4хЮZ›Ю`
lк:Nв\+ЁЮd
јљ Е®5S”Јѓ0–8KC·™lЋ›0   хУ*±ќ)°©s¬W±Аъ67µѓ)°э­cZ;P”йІљЬЃъS`c’MмґJмd
lклM8ф%Zкm¦Ац­y®u   ”йz‘Ь‹5л;LЃЌA4:зје»ж;ЗЪЃQ_{¤Юc
l/Јйд@QЋЋВТ:ьѕ№АжЎ№ќФНфS`SзXп —Р—ХЁ™Ы+?ёf(GЗ v–4vYН-L_…еЬў>2ІЉЂ=П9ЛхКґ"ќ«ї^G}lf56“х±ыzх ГjC-—"ўL'Zs‡люФ…Ы™цumК ќ„PgЦьµu8УХ9(G§ \[+ФНф9Ќн6tµр@ЊВZ¤лъ…jљ12НХ_;Јvг®<`ф±7З/7|u\]{,·кЫ>єЁ/QѓSгЯ¶љ…?IiМ)q (У·ZC4`эzђiџЉtЮ!#9¤pюж0|…Ђф8 ‡IHk9dH¶#Ю3вmШU}
M›VZђWZ8>¤ЋЄD€Ћън€Sd©o ’ФCД¤Вв1EщyE…Ещ±КшЃ—`ЄъвLх-4ЗКФ%Є©Ґ6*ЇG¬N&Ь2ЌыZ@љ—i_иbД=ЗuV{Ў    у)ҐщSKнУ7ю_Џўї©X­›о{¬•п«pr ѓБѕ67ФU+В~Eи•™¬"ьxФЧоnсqYЛpTsёцщ№Nй™,ЧOGХ+!W†ЪЏL
jЏ(.?ўґ°¤ёCF=:b~Tу!"ІЁкkІФПXBчфїWж)Fmт•оЂЛ$2cZ4a®@™ј‡>КћЎ~±_2©ыѕИј±щKЋЦЎлЩKЎ€¦щIТ\vЃК“uЎ@9ФњѕзX~sRFМђZ8Б~°Е2€арrўШЯ}=Ф+»Wr=ФUэa·AqeЪҐKiштЗЎLЯс¬IvQ\]~!nC©µ
”iј¦євЪхЏSД­§¦3‘єg\[ы4Е_®Иґ р‡+ F™^ФІО‰;тх7ЅLгп˜фДУYB#­ҐЌґfuFъ–Є¶«\[jµЫљгтo7ЪЯЌ:YWь0
U'DнvБцОMВ$Gц`GN­ъSх/"кєњtlЫZ®¶­Ў¬В@#счь)Йх|†Є¤Cю6Г®ёУедЯ„P_АЮэ6N€№—°wfV’О Eн&uq “2!фМl5*(°_Ё%n9тљвСижG^SZZRl2oВДьЙ…щSрSСЁqhZ;ЦБѓр<,џЩр6шуfгGL—?1/^ЗQ%ЕҐ#Р…O¤СЦюҐъд8B#FЌЈ?У0цCс<>кТЋ\[jЎ+ВџцodW<…ЁяфHѓtzФ„ZфЁ
uиQкСЈ>4 GChDЏc 1=љ@Sz4ѓжфh-йС
ZУгX8Ћm -=ЪБсфhиСN З‰Р‰ќб$ztЃ®фиЭйq2dРЈdТ#zТ#zСЈ7фЎЗ)Р—эbUЙЃ =‚ђK›аTzњ§Уг8“gБЩф8Тг\8ЏзГфё.ўЗЕp  =.…AфCиq\NЏ+`(=†Б•фИѓбф#й1
FУ#
и1ЖТЈ®ўЗ8(ўЗx(¦G    L ЗХ0‘“ ”ЧАdzLЃ©фё¦Щ}Ъх­¦оѕXЗ
ъ$…B 6qЌ**њTљW€‘Gъ˜§ьЅ_ЎкМшO–t6“ІY”\]GЩlКжPv=e7P6—Іх?зQ6џІ”ЭDЩBКn¦мКnҐle‹)\[ўятm”-Ґмv\]‚e”ЭAЩќ”ЭEЩr-Э©?\]цџЮъї(\[AYewS¶’І{(\[EЩЅ”­¦мѕ„?\[“рУыµvЮ 5vЋЦµлґfПФҐZ«µй-­эoТj¶l…бЩ1с‘OyyЩzФЛВЎЛ7ІR”7ІЁdФ8{^„#k<"ж‹Хв>±FЬ/ЦЪА†•\]0ў8ї(3жW%э8u7ЋЃШї7±pдHьЙ˜ўіряля<JЩc”=NЩ”=IЩzКћўмiК6P¶‘Fµg`=ћ…зис<ј@Џa3=К!LЏ-PAЏDйсјLЏW`+=^…Чис:јAЏ7a=¶Гzј;йс6јCЏwб=zјРгCШEЏЏаcz|џТг3шњ_Аnz|    {ис|MЏoа\[z|{йс=ь@Џa=~‚эфшРг`%ьїУг8HЏ?б/zь
‡ис¦Зїp„•ЫN
!$=” L¤
ЉБDљ LФѓ‰Ъ‚b0QW`&D}КPЦђІF”CYcКљPЦ”Іf”5я?ўўe-)kEYkКЋҐм8КЪPЦ–Іv”QL(ЪЉ EGA1Ў8QPL(:Љ    EA1Ўи&(&'Љ  EA1ЎИЉlA1Ўи-(&§Љ    E?A1ЎИЉ  ˜PX‚bB1@PL(NЉ3Е„в,A1Ў8GPL(ОЉуЕ„вBA1Ўё˜L\]ЉKЕ„b° ˜P\&(&WЉ    Е0A1ЎИЉ‚bB1JPL(тЕ„bЊ ˜P
Љ   Е8A1Ў/(&%‚bBqµ ˜PLЉkЕ„bЉ ˜P\+¦Сcє ч(И‡тж‚ьє /ИЧтъ‚ьї ‘@Pњ"жэмЁья·ќ?Н•kЩ1х@PzД e4g?M
ЉFЊЙ›4a"ЖУћpЪ¶E
у…y‚В<q3хК-вVz,‹й±DЬFЏҐвvz,wРгNq=–‹ф(wУcҐё‡«ДЅ±‹—pЋЭ4>ъДЗ,JiЮДьС±2¦Д§uЎЋ=,ЕЧхpШ
кБ1UџёЦх/‡У№¦†_ИлСікwRѕ…zфН-І2FM9j‚!Цэ'K:{ђІ‡({˜ІG(ЈЎTРP*h(4”
J
Ґ‚†RAC© ЎTl¤мК6Qц,eПQц<e/Pц"e›)+§,LЩ\]‚
К"”E){‰І—){…І­”ЅJЩkяй­я‹ІЧ){ѓІ7)ЫFЩvКvPцe;){;бПЮIшй»Z;mЕ|ЏІч)ыЂІ)ЫEЩGєTk\]ыDлХ§яMZ-олrѕN»№јIvјяџЕ”яb&>§мКvSц%e{(ыЉІЇ)ы†Іo)ы®j1Eм­љЗЖ$ЅФ"ѕЧїтѓgСEьиYy‰э©›хXЇБ€}яY€щAЇ~ўl?e?SvЂІ_(іЈ‘ЯЄVYДп”эAЩAКю¤м/Кю¦мРя®е—˜ЪЮ —ЇЇТq{5FьSҐuвpХєЊш·jqF©ZЎ•я—il_w;Жї-/.1qТ#&–Ћ*К·Є\ЬщЕЈhп№_#h 1•R*™"Se
™&УeMYKЦ–ud\]YOЦ§_i КFтЩX6‘Me3Щ\¶ђ-e+ЩZ+Џ“mиWЪКvтxЩ^vђе  тDЩIv–'Й.І«м&»Л“йW2d™)іdO™-{ЙЮІЏ<Eц•эd™#2Hї’+-’д©т4yє<Cћ)П’gЛsд@y®<OћЯкЛд…т"y±јD^*ЙБr€јL^.ЇђCе0y%эBћ.GИ‘r”-уeЃ#ЗКBy•'‹дшFPOЛ9A^-'КIІT^#'Л)rЄјVN“Уйгr¦њ%Ї“іеyЅјAО•7Кyrѕ\ СгФ•еНтy«\$Л%т6№TЮ.—Й;дќфб\]r№\!ЛдЭrҐјG®’чКХт>№FЮO®•ИuтAщђ|X>"•ЏЙЗетI№ћ>|J>-7ИЌт№I>+џ“ПЛд‹rіД€®ЋЛ-ІBFdTѕ$_–ЇИ­тUщљ|ќ>zCѕ)·Йнr‡|Kо”oЛwд»т=щ>}фЃьPо’ЙЏе'тSщ™ь\~!wЛ/йЈ=т+щµьF~+ї“{ечтщЈЬ'СОjЛэтgy@ю"•їЙЯет ьSюEь-ЙдaщЇ<"+(Ў¤RЌ –JQ©Є†JSйЄ¦ЄҐj«:Є.эёћЄЇЁ†Є‘:F5VMTSХ¬ФTНUХRµR­Х±к8ХFµҐ¶SЗ«цЄѓкЁNP'ЄNЄ3эр$ХEuUЭTwuІКP=T&э0KхTЩЄ—к­ъЁST_ХЏ~Ш_еЁЂ
Є\e©ђ NҐћ¦NWgЁ3ХYкluЋЁОҐћ§ОWЁХEкbu‰єT
ўVCФeкru…Є†©+U^#HWГХ5RЌRЈUѕ*PcиGcUЎєJЌSEjј*V%Ќ MMPW«‰j’*UЧЁЙфѓ)jЄєVMSУХ…f\]CНRЧ©ЩjЋє^Э@яњ«nTуФ|µ@ЭDя\ЁnV·Ё\[Х"µ˜ю№DЭ¦–ЄЫХ2uэуNu—Z®VЁ2u7эsҐєG­RчЄХк>ъзuїZ«PлФѓфП‡ФГкхЁzLб¬"U=ЎћTлХSкiъЗµQ=Ј6)њ=¤ЁзФукх"‰›U№
+њ+(UЎ"*JВKкeх
    \[Х«к5^WoЁ7IШ¦¶«$јҐvЄ·IxGЅ«Ю#б}хЃВ€PЄ\]к#z|¬(Tь©П(Ја@}aOJйZИєд˜ЄьR|I6Хюt Оw;6O&–—вьёpВ„ьСy=тІ\ЫЁj7LW_Є=рђъJнUЯЗЧЉ›$X+От¬«ЇХ7к\[х\]|ѕЭ”ќo7K<Яn‰•k¤ЎъјЋлу†П3хз№шнШКcҐн)№»ж?xjюЈэWъСЦlўївюы<а'ыфЂЦРШы&Ќ+,®ЦґЃыХПкЂъEэЄ~ДyЏХлnЮМ*`\]ш;2юЎЄ?Х_кouHэЈ«га8cБ'ЌQTд/ш‘ШЦ№ЄtmќgCc  јРpпє§€T‚цЃ^аиk‹GЊ/Х}Т”hЕ~”ЫГѕ»5Ыок?jSґ›ЅiTАtQY^щlµїЃ‡S@aW€КЅ•_ЫUn¬¬ЂЫ`Aь^&dТ±€0N‰эд\и"P!П„|h#@TVB7H•я 0NЊэОи(*ЏTЃs №ЁЬЏВhцЎP‘ітщКз`!МЈџнѓNРЙU¶*6зђ2UЁяЉ`wpzhтТЇМ\]tZ\[ЊІ«\[“ЊЁ 0їht¬цb vsNд5№ЁddIiIЫ%ЕЈу‹'еЏn*)\]#*++ҐЂzGќДc‡vОG@}hxФ
ѓIќЗ4Mє8Ню«Еiо?XMQZш&юэяв€Ј Щ«][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please share the exact error message you receive when trying to open the file with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Given your hint that the file is from a HTML game, your file is likely a **XML resource** file from an ASP.Net project as generated by Visual Studio in binary format:

> [...] When you add a resource file to a Visual Studio project, Visual Studio provides an interface for creating and maintaining a .resx file, and automatically converts the .resx file to a .resources file at compile time. You can also use a text editor to manipulate a .resx file directly. However, to avoid corrupting the file, be careful not to modify any binary information that is stored in the file.

This is a quote from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically

I suggest that you try opening that file with Visual Studio's **Solution Explorer** or programmatically, see e.g. [read string from .resx file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508570/)

Comment: Did you manage to open this file this way? I just keep getting the error "the system could not find the specified file".If you have succeeded you can please throw on the link for example to github.com so I can watch it open

Comment: Well, I have a certain resistance to open an unknown binary file with my Visual Studio Professional outside a sandbox, so I did not tried. Did you really try opening the file with VS? If so, are there any more details to the error message?

Comment: Perhaps we are mistaken and the file has some other extension

Comment: Do you have by any chance the HTML reference of it? I mean the line of code refering to your file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a .resx file that was converted into a binary .resource file.

Did you try opening it in [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net) or [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)?