# empty return variable in controller - asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Although home.dilstring data is displayed in html, when I check the data with console.write, it shows an empty value. view in html.

Why does it appear empty inside the controller of your class when loading?

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Home home = new Home();
    
        using (var db2 = new DBservice...())
        {
            Console.Write("deneme", home.dilstring); 
        }
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Home
{
    [Display(Name = "language", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string dilstring { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model ...Models.Home
    
<p class="vc_subtitle">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dilstring)
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

home object is newly instantiated object from Home class so "dilstring" property value will be empty if not assigned with default value

LabelFor will just create label element for the specified property and show it's name

so @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dilstring) will generate html below

```
 <label for="dilstring">dilstring</label>
```

if you change "LabelFor" with "DisplayFor" you will get empty value as controller

to Understand the difference try below

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
 {
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    Home home = new Home();

    using (var db2 = new DBservice...())
    {
        Console.Write("deneme", home.dilstring);
        home.dilstring = "Hi";
        Console.Write("deneme", home.dilstring);
    }
   }
   return View(home);
 }
```

And for view

```
 @model ...Models.Home

<p class="vc_subtitle">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dilstring)
</p>
<p class="vc_subtitle">
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dilstring)
</p>
```

Comment: home.dilstring I want to pull the data matching the language string from the Localization source file.

Comment: to assign value of home.dilstring from resource file just take a look on this thread   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508570/read-string-from-resx-file-in-c-sharp